# Using eval to calculate a function?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make a JS calculator, and I'm having a hard time getting through the eval part.

My HTML looks a little something like this (not literal):
`<map name="Map">

  <area shape="rect" coords="11,11,11,11" href="#" onClick=calculatenumber(7)>

  <area shape="rect" coords="11,11,11,11" href="#" onClick=calculatenumber(8)>

  <area shape="rect" coords="11,11,11,11" href="#" onClick="calculatenumber(' / ')">

  <area shape="rect" coords="11,11,11,11" href="#" onClick="calculateresult()">

</map>`

My JS looks like this:
`function calculatenumber(value){document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += value;}`

`function calculateresult(){document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = eval(calculatenumber());}`

When entered, I get undefined as an answer. It would seem that my two functions are not interacting. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: `eval` evaluates a string value as javascript. In this case `eval(document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML)` might work.

Comment: you aren't passing in a value....and why would you need to use eval.....eval is badddd

Comment: Your calculatenumber function takes an argument yet you do not pass one to it in calculateresult. Also you pass the return value from calculatenumber to eval, but calculatenumber does not return anything.

You shouldn't really be using `eval`. It's actually a really good programming excersise to implement a recursive data structure which can handle simple calculations, I'd recommend doing that.

Comment: Yes, I've since learned that eval is bad, and I'll be looking for alternatives once I get this thing to work. Thanks for the comments all.